# Почему при переопределении собственного хэш кода рекомендуют использовать значение 31?

Tags: java, хеширование, hashcode

кто может объяснить этот кусочек кода ?

я его видел в примерах но не совсем понимаю как работает такой хэш код

почему число 31 ? я смотрю в том числе и на английской версии сайта все пишут разные , кто то даже советует 73 потому что любимое число шелдона купера. народ, мне нужен ваш совет :)))

почему при переопределении собственного хэш кода рекомендуют использовать значение 31 ?

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) re;
    result = prime * result + (int) im;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Множитель 31 выбран потому, что является простым нечётным числом. Если
>   бы это было чётное число и при умножении произошло переполнение,
>   информация была бы потеряна, поскольку умножение числа на 2
>   равнозначно его арифметическому сдвигу. Хотя преимущества от
>   использования простых чисел не столь очевидны, именно их принято
>   использовать для этой цели. Замечательное свойство числа 31
>   заключается в том, что умножение может быть заменено сдвигом и
>   вычитанием для лучшей производительности: `31 * i == (i << 5) - i`.
>   Современные виртуальные машины автоматически выполняют эту небольшую
>   оптимизацию.

Джошуа Блох "Java Эффективное программирование", глава 3, статья 9

Comment: да, но почему некоторые программисты используют другие числа ?

Comment: @AlexeySeliverstov это уже другой вопрос и задавать его нужно этим некоторым программистам.